# Заголовок столбца

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Можно ли как-то, используя PHP создать столбец с именем, к примеру "2018-02-09" ?

Когда выполняю заброс в sql

```
ALTER TABLE `name` ADD `24-08-2018` VARCHAR(200)
```

Все создается, а когда через PHP:

`$queryAddColumns = mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE name ADD {$teststst} VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL") or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));`

Выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2018-02-09 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: интересно почему в сообщении об ошибке двойные кавычки, там текст один к одному из запроса обычно ... А вообще странное название для столбца. да создавать столбцы по одному да еще с датами, спорное решение. БД должна быть спроектирована так, что бы во время работы приложения ее структура не менялась. например записи за даты могли бы хранится в отдельной таблице по записи на каждую дату

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень бы не рекомендовал такую реализацию. Лучше создать другую таблицу, 
 связать их, сделав записи типа:

```
-------------------------------------
|id|you_table_id|date   |   value   |
-------------------------------------
| 2|    34      |2018-08|Ваша запись
```

Но отвечая на ваш вопрос - попробуйте вот так:

```
$queryAddColumns = mysqli_query($link,
    'ALTER TABLE `name` ADD `' . $teststst . '` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL'
) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
```